# dict comprehension with unique keys out of list

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

i have used list comprehensions not very often but i was wondering if the below lines can be a one liner (yes the code is already small, but i am curious):

```
lst = ['hi', 'hello', 'bob', 'hello', 'bob', 'hello']
for index in lst:
    data[index] = data.get(index,0) + 1
```

data would be: {'hi':1, 'hello':3, 'bob':2}

something:

d = { ... for index in lst } ????

I have tried some comprehensions but they don't work:

```
d = { index:key for index in lst if index in d: key = key + 1 else key = 1 }
```

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nsh, but i was thinking of using minimal needed python modules, so no additional imports! Any other possibility to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an
>   unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and
>   their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be
>   any integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class
>   is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.

```
import collections
l = ['hi', 'hello', 'bob', 'hello', 'bob', 'hello']
c = collections.Counter(l)
assert c['hello'] == 3
```